# Image rotator in JavaScript (keydown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, box2d, keydown

I have a problem with animation in JavaScript. I using code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777861/simple-javascript-image-rotator) and this code is in my function for keydown. But code does not work. Itself code from link is ok, but in function with keydown does not work correctly. Animated object stays by first image (dog1.PNG) and next image does not show. Can you help me?

```js
$(function() {
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 39:

            var quotes = new Array("dog1.PNG", "gog2.PNG");
            var i = 0;

            function animation() {
              document.getElementById("dog").src = ("images/" + quotes[i]);
              if (i < 1) {
                i++;
              } else
                i = 0;

              setTimeout("animation()", 250);
            }
            animation();

            //speed objects in Box2D
            var vel = new b2Vec2(150, 0);

            game.dog.SetLinearVelocity(vel);

            break;
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="animation()">
  <img src="images/dog.PNG" id="dog" />
</body>
```

Comment: Why are there two body elements? If you don't know what that is I suggest you first read some basic books about HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: What elements? Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the function "animation" being inside the keydown event: Scope problem

Have you checked the browser console pressing F12 to see if it shows you any javascript errors when it loads?

Try this:

```
var i = 0 ;
function animation(){   
    document.getElementById("dog").src = ( "images/" + quotes[i] );
    if (i<1){
        i++;
    }
    else
        i = 0;

    setTimeout("animation()", 250);
} 

$(document).keydown(function(e){

    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            var quotes = new Array ("dog1.PNG","gog2.PNG");
            animation();

            //I commented this lines because you mentioned the problem was with the animation. You can debug this later
            //speed objects in Box2D
            //var vel = new b2Vec2(150, 0);

            //game.dog.SetLinearVelocity( vel );  
        break;
}
```

Also make sure your Javascript is inserted in the page in the head section:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script>//Javascript code goes here</script>
    </head>
    <body onload=....>
        //Your html
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I put before function with keydown, but code works for all file and I do not want this, because my object (dog) is throughout animated. I nedd animated object when I press key.